# Using Python to edit CDATA tag in XML and create a new XML file

Tags: python, xml, editing

To start with, I am not very experienced using python or xml.

I am attempting to parse through an XML file using python and change the name within Character Data tags, then create a new xml file with the updated names.

I used some code I found on stack overflow, and it partially works. My program will read my old xml file, update the CDATA tag name, and create the new xml file. However, the `<![CDATA[]]>` is being omitted in my new xml file.

How can I get python to include the  when writing to my new xml file?

**This is my XML file:**

```
<Programs Use="Context">
    <Program Use="Target" Name="MainProgram" TestEdits="false" MainRoutineName="MainRoutine"        Disabled="false" UseAsFolder="false">
        <Tags/>
            <Routines>
                <Routine Name="MainRoutine" Type="RLL">
                    <RLLContent>
                        <Rung Number="0" Type="N">
                            <Text>
                                <![CDATA[XIC(AutoSlateAutoRun);]]>
                            </Text>
                        </Rung>
                    </RLLContent>
                </Routine>
            </Routines>
    </Program>
</Programs>
```

**This is the python code I am using:**

def create_l5x_import_file():

```
with open('ProgramExport.L5X', encoding='UTF-8-SIG') as f:
    tree = ET.parse(f)
    root = tree.getroot() 
    
for elem in root.iter():   
    
    try:
        elem.text = elem.text.replace("(AutoSlateAutoRun)", "(THIS_IS_NEW)")
    except AttributeError:
        pass
      
tree.write('ProgramOutput.L5X', xml_declaration=True, method='xml', encoding='UTF-8-SIG')
```

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for your task.

Comment: Is there a problem with the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` not being there? For example, is there a downstream system that requires them to be there? Any sane program that handles XML should treat `<Text><![CDATA[SomeTextHere]]></Text>` and `<Text>SomeTextHere</Text>` identically.

Comment: @LukeWoodward, I honestly haven't tried to use the program without the <[CDATA[]]>.  However, I accomplished what I was wanting to do without using elementtree. The code just isn't as clean now.